# Recover file in directory made into a file

Tags: chmod

After making all files in a directory non-executable with chmod I realized that one of them was a directory. Unfortunately, it holds a file. Because it is no longer a directory I cannot access or recover or move the file held by it.
Is there any way to recover it?

Answer (score 0):

It's still a directory, you just can't navigate it without execute permission. You should be able to `chmod +x thedirectory`.